# Sending a value from a textbox on a View as a parameter to an action in a controller using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing

I have an `Index` view - all that's on this View is a textbox and a submit button.  I would like, when the user submits the form, for the value in the textbox to go to the controller I specify in my `Form` action.  Here's the code for my `Index` view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MovieDetails", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" class="typeahead-devs" id="movieName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Create" name="Submit" />
}
```

When I click Submit, it takes me to the action `MovieDetails`:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MovieDetails(string movieName)
        {
            response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("api/sixfilm?movieName={0}", movieName)).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var actors = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Actor>>().Result;
                return View(actors);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

But, `movieName` is `null`.  Any ideas why `movieName` is null and how I can send a textbox's value over to an action?

Comment: Sweet, another unexplained downvote.  SO frustrating when you don't tell me what I did wrong/should have put/etc.

Comment: +1 for a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not name your text input. Change

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead-devs" id="movieName" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead-devs" id="movieName" name="movieName" />
```